IIS 6 and script execution timeout not updating
I have an ASP.NET application, .NET version 4.8 running on IIS version 6. One page is timing out occasionally returning the message ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
I am attempting to increase the script execution timeout for that page. I have tried:

adding Server.ScriptTimeout = xx in the controller for that view
adding Server.ScriptTimeout = xx at the top of the view
adding <httpRuntime executionTimeout="xx" /> to the web.config

None of these appear to change the script timeout from the default of 110 seconds.
How can I increase the timeout?

IIS 6 End of life was 2015- you should look at updating
